# How to get Gmail User profile Name?

Tags: gmail, profile

I have more than 2000gmail address. I need to get Gmail Profile Name from each gmail.addresses. how to do that? Any google sheets or online solution? Please let me know.

Note: Profile Name means the combination of a users First Name & Last Name

I tried searching online solution but couldn’t found.

Comment: Hi and welcome here. Maybe your question is out of the scope of SO. Here, you have to submit code you have written, with which you encounter a technical issue.

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]